# Can't create a new Certificate Signing Request(CSR)?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, csr

I am trying to test my app on my iOS device. To do so I ill need to create a `Certificate Signing Request`(`CSR`).

These are the steps I took:

- Open `Keychain Access` in the Utilities folder.
- On the drop down menu clicked <kbd>Keychain Access</kbd> → <kbd>Certificate assistant</kbd> → <kbd>Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority</kbd>
- Entered my apple id email address and my name
- ticked `Save to disk`
- Clicked <kbd>continue</kbd>
- Save the CSR on desktop

Then the error:

```
The specified keychain is not a valid keychain file
```

I have tried the search engine for answers and I had no luck! Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this question! Here are the steps:

Go to your terminal and type in:

```
ls -l ~/Library/
```

This will make sure that the permissions on the keychain folder are correct.

privs on the Keychains folder should be

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

If it is not `drwxr-xr-x` then follow these steps:

- Go to the drop down menu in Keychain Access.
- Keychain Access > Keychain First Aid
- Enter your `Username` and `Password`
- Tick on `Repair`
- Click **Start**

This solved my problem! :)

Comment: What dropdown? I don't see any options for keychain first aid

Comment: @CalZone This answer was from 2013. Its been 5 years..?

Comment: So what? Even in 2021 I'm looking this up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch Keychain Access located in `/Applications/Utilities` directly. I did it and it worked for me :)